# SonarQube analysis through maven is taking a long time

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I am facing a strange problem with Sonar analysis.
Sonar version - 4.5.4
DB - Postgres

I am running sonar on a big project (LOC - 470K). When I run sonar in one go with command "mvn clean install sonar:sonar", the analysis takes more than 5 hours.
But when I break it up in two commands (i.e. doing "mvn clean install" first and running "mvn sonar:sonar") the analysis finishes in less than 30 minutes.
In both cases the LoC remains same and reports are exactly same.

Any hints to fix this ?

Since I use Jenkins on which I do not have control over build parameters, I want to finish it in one go (& that too quickly).

Comment: There is not enough information to help you out here. Is this a multimodule project ? is there coverage configured in your pom ? how ? which version of sonar maven plugin are you using ? which version of the sonar java plugin ?

Comment: Maybe you are a bit short in term of memory. Try increasing Xmx using MAVEN_OPTS env variable.

Comment: Yes, it is a multimodule project and coverage is configured in pom using Jacoco.

Comment: sonar-maven-plugin version being used is 2.5 and sonarqube version is 4.5.4. Sonar Java version is 3.5.

Comment: Julien, not sure if it related to memory but the fact is that it does complete in 15 minutes when I run it separately (mvn sonar:sonar).